# Changing from recvfrom() to recvmsg() increases packet loss

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I am listening to a multicast feed. Each packet contains a sequence number, so I know when I receive an unexpected packet.

Initially I used `recvfrom()` but I wanted to obtain the NIC timestamp, so I changed to `recvmsg()`.

When I use `recvfrom()` I rarely miss packets:

```
while(1)
{
    const size_t maxNumBytesToRead = MSGBUFSIZE - 1;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(_sin);
    const int nbytes = recvfrom(sock, _msgbuf, maxNumBytesToRead, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &_sin, &addrlen);
```

where:

```
#define MSGBUFSIZE 1500
char _msgbuf[MSGBUFSIZE];
struct sockaddr_in _sin;
```

However, when I convert my code to use `recvmsg()` I lose a lot of packets:

```
while(1)
{
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    char control[1024];

    iov.iov_base = _msgbuf;
    iov.iov_len = MSGBUFSIZE;
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_name = &_sin;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_control = control;
    msg.msg_controllen = 1024;

    const int nbytes = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);
```

The code following `recvfrom()` and `recvmsg()` decodes the packets and is identical.

I am switching between the two designs and `recvmsg()` ALWAYS loses packets and `recvfrom()` rarely loses packets, so I must have a bug or misunderstanding.

Can anyone see something which would explain this?

Comment: When you are loosing packets, are you loosing all packets or only some of them ?

Comment: @Dhruv I am reading the next packet and comparing the received sequence number with the expected sequence number. The "unexpected packet" is complete. I have to re-request the missing packet.

Comment: are both "client" and "server" app on the same computer ? or are you sending it over the network ? Do you have WireShark running ?

Comment: How do you create the socket, and what options have you set on it?

Comment: can you try ```int recvmmsg ( Socket, MessageVec, Num_msg,  Flags, Timeout) ```instead ?

Comment: It would have been prudent to check *why* you're losing packets in the first place. Are you CPU-bound? Are there not enough buffers? Do the packets even reach the NIC or are they lost before?

Comment: There's a one-byte difference in the lengths you're passing. Not sure if that makes a difference but it might affect truncation and what your own code is doing with the results..?

Comment: You might use `strace -T` to see if there's a difference in the time spent in the syscall.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response. The problem seemed to disappear so I'm not really sure what the cause was.